# Attempt to invoke virtual method android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' null object reference

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, cursor

Ok, sou novo em Android e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação um tanto complexa pra uma conclusão de curso. No momento o problema é exibir uma listview com informações de um database local(SQLite). Eu ficaria mais calmo se não fosse o fato de já ter feito uma listview no mesmo formato que deu certo, e essa não. Abaixo o erro, seguido do LogCat.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.banhammer.bookswap, PID: 30658
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.banhammer.bookswap/com.banhammer.bookswap.Activities.EstanteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                  at com.banhammer.bookswap.DAO.LivroDAO2.showEstante(LivroDAO2.java:67)
                  at com.banhammer.bookswap.Activities.EstanteActivity.onCreate(EstanteActivity.java:31)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Estou tentando carregar a lista com os dados do banco através de de uma DAO bem simples. O primeiro método funciona e o segundo não:

```
public ArrayList<Livro> procurarLivro(String parametro) {
    bsdb.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Livro> listL = new ArrayList<Livro>();
    Cursor Cr = db.rawQuery("select * from uBooks where titulo='"+parametro+"' and trocavel='Disponível';",null);
    while (Cr.moveToNext()) {
        Livro l = new Livro();
        l.setTitulo(Cr.getString(1));
        l.setAutor(Cr.getString(2));
        l.setGenero1(Cr.getString(3));
        l.setGenero2(Cr.getString(4));
        listL.add(l);
    }
    db.close();
    Cr.close();
    return listL;
}

public ArrayList<Livro> showEstante() {
    bsdb.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Livro> listL = new ArrayList<Livro>();
    Cursor Cr = db.rawQuery("select * from uBooks;",null);
    while (Cr.moveToNext()) {
        Livro l = new Livro();
        l.setTitulo(Cr.getString(1));
        l.setAutor(Cr.getString(2));
        l.setGenero1(Cr.getString(3));
        l.setGenero2(Cr.getString(4));
        listL.add(l);
    }
    db.close();
    Cr.close();
    return listL;
}
```

Essa aqui é a activity que dá problema. Ela nem inicializa porque a lista está sendo gerada na criação.

```
package com.banhammer.bookswap.Activities;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.banhammer.bookswap.DAO.Livro;
import com.banhammer.bookswap.DAO.LivroDAO2;
import com.banhammer.bookswap.R;

import java.util.List;


public class EstanteActivity extends ListActivity {

    private LivroDAO2 LDAO2;
    ImageButton home;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estante);
        LDAO2=new LivroDAO2(this);

        home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cad_home);

        List<Livro> estante=LDAO2.showEstante();
        ArrayAdapter<Livro> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Livro>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,estante);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    public void estHome(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LDAO2.fechar();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Se alguem tiver uma solução ou uma ideia seria muito bem vindo. Eu tentei tudo que eu sabia e nada de arrumar isso.

Comment: O erro é por o Cursor `cr` ser nulo. Se o primeiro método(procurarLivro) funciona não encontro razão para o outro não funcionar.

Comment: Está faltando informações importantes no seu código para poder confirmar uma resposta, por exemplo esse `bsdb.` que não é mostrado onde é instanciado.

Comment: Qual é query que está errada?

Comment: a segunda query que está dando erros. O `bsdb.` está instanciado no inicio do código:

    `public class LivroDAO2 {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private BookSwapOpenHelper bsdb;
    public LivroDAO2(Context c) {
        bsdb = new BookSwapOpenHelper(c);
    }
    public void abrir() {
        db = bsdb.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void fechar() {
        db.close();
    }
`

Answer (score -2):

Antes de usar o cursor, tente colocar uma verificação do género(uma maneira de contornar o erro, mas não o resolve)

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
```

Se continuar a dar erro, penso que tenha a ver com o ";" que tem no final da query.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Isso não resolve o erro apenas o contorna.

Comment: pois, o problema dele está na query que usa não? os dados podem não existir na DB por isso é que retorna null. Vou editar a minha resposta, como uma maneira de contornar o erro

Comment: Não é suposto o cursor ser nulo. Se não existirem dados que satisfaçam a query é retornado um cursor vazio(`moveToFirst()`retorna `false`),

Comment: exatamente! o problema está na query

Comment: O que tem de errado na query? Se, como o AP diz, a primeira funciona, porque é que a segunda não?

Comment: não tenho certeza do que causou o problema, mas acredito que foi a estrutura da query. Pesquisei um pouco sobre como o RawQuery funciona e escrevi dessa forma: `Cursor Cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM uBooks WHERE trocavel=?;",new String[]{"Indisponível"});`
Agora a list carrega os dados.